# Range.Autofilter is NOT filtering correct column

Tags: vba, autofilter

I'm having a problem with my autofilter vba code where it's skipping the first column for some reason and taking field "4" as column E (the 5th column). This is extra odd because on some other files with the same exact setup, it doesn't do this, but for others it does. I can't put my finger on what the issue is (whether it's code or the actual spreadsheet). See the code below. Appreciate any help!

```
 Workbooks(Num14).Sheets(1).Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="REP"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had to turn off autofiltermode first and then have the macro run the autofilter code. For some reason, the filter on the spreadsheet wasn't allowing for proper autofiltering. Hope this helps others!